# Derivative cycles of length 8

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let's say I want to find derivative cycles, that is, a group of functions $\langle f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_{n-1} \rangle$ where ${f_0}^{(p)}(x)={f_{p\,\%\,n}}(x)$ where $\%$ is the modulo operator.

- For $n = 1$, we have the exponential function, $f_0 = ae^{x+k}$ for arbitrary $a$ and $k$.
- For $n = 2$, we have [two of these exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1256140/166367), $f_0 = ae^{x+k} + be^{-x-k}$ for arbitrary $a$, $b$, and $k$.
- For $n = 4$, an obvious solution is $\langle a\sin(x + k), a\cos(x + k), -a\sin(x + k), -a\cos(x + k) \rangle$

… but wait! That's just *more exponentials!*

$$
f_0 = ae^{x + k} + be^{ix + ik} + ce^{-x - k} + de^{-ix-ik}
$$

gives the general solution, for arbitrary $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $k$ (discard the results when they become complex, I only care about $f_0: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$).

There seems to be something going on when $n$ is a power of 2, so what functions could be in a derivative cycle with $n = 8$? Since, in our exponent, we progressed from "one direction of number" ($1$) to "two directions of number" ($\pm1$) to "four directions of number" ($\pm1$ and $\pm i$), will we have to use a number system next that has 8 directions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $r$ is a complex number satisfying $r^8=1$, then the real and imaginary parts of $f(x)=e^{rx}$ will have derivatives repeating in cycles of eight.

With $r=(1+i)/\sqrt2$ we get
$$
f(x)=e^{x/\sqrt2}(\cos\frac x{\sqrt2}+i\sin\frac x{\sqrt2}).
$$

You can get any period $n$ by choosing $r=\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$ and
$$f(x)=e^{x\cos\frac{2\pi}n}\cos(x\sin\frac{2\pi}n).$$

Answer (score 5):

Let us start in the complex numbers.

The  $n$-th derivative of $\exp(r x)$ is $r^n \exp(r x)$. You want $r^n= 1$. So you need that $r$ is an [$n$-th root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

You can then combine the complex functions for distinct roots of unity to get real functions.

This does not only work for powers of two.